# combining StateT with InputT

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

It is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908718/keeping-track-of-history-in-ghci). I'm trying to combine `shell` from @ErikR's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37909749/165753) in my `InputT` loop.

```
main :: IO [String]
main = do
    c <- makeCounter
    execStateT (repl c) []

repl :: Counter -> StateT [String] IO ()
repl c = lift $ runInputT defaultSettings loop
  where
  loop = do
    minput <- getLineIO $ in_ps1 $ c
    case minput of
      Nothing -> lift $ outputStrLn "Goodbye."
      Just input -> (liftIO $ process c input) >> loop

getLineIO :: (MonadException m) => IO String -> InputT m (Maybe String)
getLineIO ios = do
    s <- liftIO ios
    getInputLine s
```

And getting an error

```
Main.hs:59:10:
    Couldn't match type ‘InputT m0’ with ‘IO’
    Expected type: StateT [String] IO ()
      Actual type: StateT [String] (InputT m0) ()
    Relevant bindings include
      loop :: InputT (InputT m0) () (bound at Main.hs:61:3)
    In the expression: lift $ runInputT defaultSettings loop
    In an equation for ‘repl’:
        repl c
          = lift $ runInputT defaultSettings loop
          where
              loop
                = do { minput <- getLineIO $ in_ps1 $ c;
                       .... }

Main.hs:62:5:
No instance for (Monad m0) arising from a do statement
The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  loop :: InputT (InputT m0) () (bound at Main.hs:61:3)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Monad (Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m)
    -- Defined in ‘Text.Parsec.Prim’
  instance Monad (Either e) -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
  instance Monad Data.Proxy.Proxy -- Defined in ‘Data.Proxy’
  ...plus 15 others
In a stmt of a 'do' block: minput <- getLineIO $ in_ps1 $ c
In the expression:
  do { minput <- getLineIO $ in_ps1 $ c;
       case minput of {
         Nothing -> lift $ outputStrLn "Goodbye."
         Just input -> (liftIO $ process c input) >> loop } }
In an equation for ‘loop’:
    loop
      = do { minput <- getLineIO $ in_ps1 $ c;
             case minput of {
               Nothing -> lift $ outputStrLn "Goodbye."
               Just input -> (liftIO $ process c input) >> loop } }
```

The full code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/dimidd/452c772371ad131055a49cd67957f201), it's based on [Write you a haskell](https://github.com/sdiehl/write-you-a-haskell/blob/master/chapter4/untyped/Main.hs).

I know `haskelline` has a built-in support for history, but I'm trying to implement it myself as an exercise.

Feel free to suggest replacements for the monad transformers to get the same functionality.

**My Real Problem**

I'd like to add `ipython` like capabilities to the lambda REPL in Write You a Haskell, namely:

I. A counter for input and output, that will appear in the prompt, i.e

```
In[1]>
Out[1]>
```

This is already [done](https://github.com/dimidd/write-you-a-haskell/blob/master/chapter4/untyped/Main.hs).

II. Save each command to history (automatically), and display all previous commands using a special command, e.g. `histInput` (same as `hist` in `ipython`). Also, save a history of all output results and display them using `histOutput`. This is what I'm trying to do in this question (input history only for the moment).

III. Reference previous inputs and outputs, e.g. if `In[1]` was `x`, then `In[1] + 2` should be substituted by `x + 2`, and likewise for the output.

**Update**

I've tried to combine @ErikR's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980156/165753), and temporarily disabled `showStep`, coming up with:

```
module Main where

import Syntax
import Parser
import Eval
import Pretty
import Counter

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import System.Console.Haskeline
import Control.Monad.State

showStep :: (Int, Expr) -> IO ()
showStep (d, x) = putStrLn ((replicate d ' ') ++ "=> " ++ ppexpr x)

process :: Counter -> String -> InputT (StateT [String] IO) ()
process c line =
    if ((length line) > 0)
       then
        if (head line) /= '%'
            then do
                modify (++ [line])
                let res = parseExpr line
                case res of
                    Left err -> outputStrLn $ show err
                    Right ex -> do
                        let (out, ~steps) = runEval ex
                        --mapM_ showStep steps
                        out_ps1 c $ out2iout $ show out
        else do
                let iout = handle_cmd line
                out_ps1 c iout

    -- TODO: don't increment counter for empty lines
    else do
      outputStrLn ""

out2iout :: String -> IO String
out2iout s = return s

out_ps1 :: Counter -> IO String -> InputT (StateT [String] IO) ()
out_ps1 c iout = do
      out <- liftIO iout
      let out_count = c 0
      outputStrLn $ "Out[" ++ (show out_count) ++ "]: " ++ out
      outputStrLn ""

handle_cmd :: String -> IO String
handle_cmd line = if line == "%hist"
                     then
                        evalStateT getHist []
                     else
                         return "unknown cmd"

getHist :: StateT [String] IO String
getHist = do
    hist <- lift get
    forM_ (zip [(1::Int)..] hist) $ \(i, h) -> do
                                show i ++ ": " ++ show h

main :: IO ()
main = do
    c <- makeCounter
    repl c

repl :: Counter -> IO ()
repl c = evalStateT (runInputT defaultSettings(loop c)) []

loop :: Counter -> InputT (StateT [String] IO) ()
loop c = do
    minput <- getLineIO $ in_ps1 $ c
    case minput of
      Nothing -> return ()
      Just input -> process c input >> loop c

getLineIO :: (MonadException m) => IO String -> InputT m (Maybe String)
getLineIO ios = do
    s <- liftIO ios
    getInputLine s

in_ps1 :: Counter -> IO String
in_ps1 c = do
    let ion = c 1
    n <- ion
    let s = "Untyped: In[" ++ (show n) ++ "]> "
    return s
```

which still doesn't compile:

```
Main.hs:59:5:
    Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘StateT [String] IO’
    Expected type: StateT [String] IO String
      Actual type: [()]
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      forM_ (zip [(1 :: Int) .. ] hist)
      $ \ (i, h) -> do { show i ++ ": " ++ show h }
    In the expression:
      do { hist <- lift get;
           forM_ (zip [(1 :: Int) .. ] hist) $ \ (i, h) -> do { ... } }
    In an equation for ‘getHist’:
        getHist
          = do { hist <- lift get;
                 forM_ (zip [(1 :: Int) .. ] hist) $ \ (i, h) -> ... }
```

Comment: haskeline already implements command line history for you - have a look at the [usage example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.7.2.3/docs/System-Console-Haskeline.html)

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I want to implement it myself as an exercise.

Comment: If you want to implement history yourself, why does `InputT` appear in your code?

Comment: It's taken from from Stephen Diehl's original code in WYAH. I don't need `InputT` per se, I just need to get an input line with a custom prompt and thus using `getInputLine`, whose type is `(MonadException m) =>  String -> InputT m (Maybe String)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a guess at what you are trying to do.

This program recognizes the following commands:

```
hist        -- show current history
add xxx     -- add xxx to the history list
clear       -- clear the history list
count       -- show the count of history items
quit        -- quit the command loop
```

Program source:

```
import System.Console.Haskeline
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = evalStateT (runInputT defaultSettings loop) []

loop :: InputT (StateT [String] IO) ()
loop = do
  minput <- getInputLine "% "
  case minput of
      Nothing -> return ()
      Just "quit" -> return ()
      Just input -> process input >> loop

process input = do
  let args = words input
  case args of
    []  -> return ()
    ("hist": _)     -> showHistory
    ("add" : x : _) -> lift $ modify (++ [x]) 
    ("clear": _)    -> lift $ modify (const [])
    ("count": _)    -> do hs <- lift get
                          outputStrLn $ "number of history items: " ++ show (length hs)
    _               -> outputStrLn "???"

showHistory = do
  hist <- lift get
  forM_ (zip [(1::Int)..] hist) $ \(i,h) -> do
    outputStrLn $ show i ++ " " ++ h
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll add a description of my real problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is because you have declared

```
main :: IO ()
```

but also

```
execStateT (...) :: IO [String]
```

`execStateT` returns the computation's final state, and your state is of type `[String]`. Usually this is fixed by just not declaring a type for `main` and letting it be inferred to be `IO a` for some `a`. The second one I'm not sure about, but maybe it's the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, the first error was solved by changing to `main :: IO [String]
`. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have [here](https://github.com/dimidd/write-you-a-haskell/blob/8ab42e0997427278b44f7c952576386dc2c65c10/chapter4/untyped/Main.hs) compiles, and it defines `process` as:

```
process :: Counter -> String -> IO ()
```

To create a version of `process` with this signature:

```
Counter -> String -> InputT (StateT [String] IO) ()
```

just use liftIO:

```
process' :: Counter -> String -> InputT (StateT [String] IO) ()
process' counter str = liftIO $ process counter str
```

Comment: Thanks, It does compile, but lacks the history logic. How would you suggest to add it? Specifically, how will I be able to use `get` in `showHistory`, if it's not inside a state monad or am I missing something?

Comment: I've also tried to call `showHist` from `process'`, and got stuck by another [error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38071560/165753).